# postback empties checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a checkboxlist, to which data is bound in page load. The selected items have to be saved in db. But when I click on submit, the count of items in checkboxlist is 0. How can this be fixed.

Cannot use a session variable, as there are multiple servers.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server"                            
 AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="type" 
 DataValueField="typeid" EnableViewState="true">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostback)
   {
     FillCheckboxList();
     int count = cbl.Items.count; // can see 15 here
   }
}

protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int count = cbl.Items.count; //Now 0 here 
   if(cbl.Items.count > 0)
      {
        //............
      }
}
```

There is no where else that the checkboxlist is emptied.

Comment: "Cannot use a session variable, as there are multiple servers." - Sure you can - you just have to use a farmable session store (DB, file)

Comment: Is ViewState disabled for any controls?  Is this control in your markup or added in code?

Comment: Dont know how to do that. But why isnt the above code working. Any other workaround

Comment: The asp.net checkboxlist control's viewstate is enabled

Comment: What is `page_load` at all? That's not the default `Page_Load`-event. From wher and when do you call it?

Comment: Viewstate is hierarchical so if you disable the view state on the page or another control that wraps your DropDown, it will still be disabled.  Also, if you have multiple servers without persistent load balancing, you have to make sure the ViewState is encrypted with the same keys.

Comment: @ jtimperley. That helped. The page's viewstate was set to false. Changed it and it's all good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too: it was because (as mentioned in a comment) the viewstate was disabled for the page or a parent control of the CheckBoxList (and fixed by not disabling that viewstate).